# Extract specified text from Column in Python (Google Colabs)

Tags: python, string, dataframe, extract

I'm looking to extract specified data from the below table in Python (Google Colabs).

```html
<style type="text/css">
    table.tableizer-table {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    } 
    .tableizer-table td {
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
    }
    .tableizer-table th {
        background-color: #104E8B; 
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Source</th><th>Description</th><th>Services</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>Receivable Invoice</td><td>Peter Jackson - 2/2/2022 - Access Community, Social And Rec Activities - Standard - Weekday Daytime - TTP 9:00AM 12:00PM 04_104_0125_6_1_T</td><td>Access Community, Social And Rec Activities - Standard - Weekday Daytime - TTP 9:00AM 12:00PM 04_104_0125_6_1_T</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Receivable Invoice</td><td>Helen Johnson - 30/06/2021- - Transport 04_590_0125_6_1</td><td>Transport 04_590_0125_6_1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Receivable Invoice</td><td>Charlotte Jane - Reversal of difference charged Domestic shifts from 22/9/2021 - 31/12/2021</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Receivable Invoice</td><td>Mary Jane - Support Coordination - 10/3/2022 - Psychosocial Recovery Coaching - Weekday Daytime 07_101_0106_6_3</td><td>Psychosocial Recovery Coaching - Weekday Daytime 07_101_0106_6_3</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Above shows the Table that I want in Python. The Column "Services" is the extract specified text from Column "Description".

As you can see, there are few data which shouldn't pick up, for instance Row 3.

I have been stuck in this code for the past few days, appreciate if anyone could provide a lead.

Expected outcome is Column "Services".

Comment: please add your code, and the expected output

Comment: @Hanna I didn't find the proper code for it, hence I'm struggling. Expected outcome is Column "Services".

I found the below code,however it didn't give the correct output since I'm not sure how to define.

export['Services'] = export['Description'].str.extract('Access\s')